# Include shared resource in ResourceDictionaries for multiple controls

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a `DataTemplate` I'd like to use with multiple `ContentControl`s. But each of these controls needs to contain additional `DataTemplate`s as well, and the final list is different for each one. Something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FooDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type Foo}" />

<!-- snip -->

<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Bar}" />
        <!-- Also want a copy of FooDataTemplate here, but without an explicit key -->
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>

<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Baz}" />
        <!-- Also want a copy of FooDataTemplate here, but without an explicit key -->
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

Is there a XAML syntax that will let me do this? I could create an "AddResourceToDictionary" attached behavior or put FooDataTemplate in its own resource dictionary file and merge it in, but both seem like an awful lot of hassle for a simple thing...

Comment: What if you just drop `x:Key="FooDataTemplate"` and thus have it applied automatically?

Comment: @Clemens That would work, but then the template is applied over a wider scope than I want

Answer (score 1):

You could add `FooDataTemplate` to the `ContentControl's` `ResourceDictionary`, provided that it's in scope:

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Bar}" />
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="FooDataTemplate" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

But if you want a "copy of FooDataTemplate, but without an explicit key", you need to create a new `DataTemplate` yourself. There is no XAML syntax that lets you base a `DataTemplate` on another one. A template must be defined as a whole. So I guess the answer to your question is simply no.

`FooDataTemplate` can only be referenced and used as-is. And since it's already in scope, it doesn't really make any sense adding it to the `ContentControl's` `ResourceDictionary`.

Comment: I actually tried the `StaticResource` thing, but it caused a XAML parse exception. It does basically reflect what I want to do though: add an existing, keyed DataTemplate resource to a different resource dictionary under a different (default) key. Maybe I will just have to seek out a different approach...

Comment: @dlf: What does the XAML parse exception say?

Comment: Different things depending on whether I include it before or after the other resources :) ("Value nodes must be followed by EndMember", "Missing key value on 'StaticResourceHolder' object"). But I gather that it's trying to add the StaticResourceExtension object itself to the dictionary rather than the object returned by StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValue.

Comment: @dlf: Did you add the `<ResourceDictionary>` element as per my example?

Comment: The "EndMember" exception may have actually been from an earlier iteration where it was missing, but the "Missing key value" error occurs regardless of whether there's an explicit `ResourceDictionary` node or not.